# background gui process in shell script

Tags: shell-script

In the below script, ivfstudio commands open a gui.
Even launched as a background process, I need to close it first so that the next commands are executed. **How to make it "really background" ?**

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd=`ivfstudio ilv/my_app.iva -execute GenerateAll `;

(
$cmd & ;
echo "toto" ;
`sleep 30` ;
PID = `ps aux | grep -i ivfs | grep my_user| grep -i generateall | awk -F " " '{print $2}' \`;  ) ) ` ;
echo  $(PID) ;
`kill $(PID)` ;
)

exit
```

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd="ivfstudio my_project.iva -execute GenerateAll > /dev/null 2> /dev/null"

nohup $cmd &
echo "toto"

`sleep 30`
PID=`ps aux | grep -i ivfs | grep my_user| grep -i generateall | awk -F " " '{print $2}' `

echo  $PID
`kill $PID`


exit
```

Comment: I think you have to use: `nohup nohup command &`

Comment: `cmd = 'ivfstudio my_project.iva -execute GenerateAll'
    
    nohup nohup $cmd &
`
is not working... How shall I type it exactely ?

Comment: @user62122 , thanks a lot, I made it work thanks to you.

Comment: answers should be in the Answer box -- feel free to write one up yourself, or @user62122!